# Is there a counter for a dog's barking? Or more generally, a counter for sounds?

Tags: word-requests, counters

Had the thought while chatting online about whether there is a counter for barks from a dog or possibly one for distinct sounds in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say ひと[吠]{ほ}え and ふた吠え in the case of a dog’s barking. 吠え is a noun form of the verb 吠える (“to bark”). I cannot think of any realistic scenario where I would keep counting a dog’s barks beyond two, or maybe three, using this counter, though. I would most likely say:

> 犬が３回吠えた。

More generally, if the sounds come from an animal, you could use [声]{こえ}. In fact, there is this phrase, [鶴の一声](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%B6%B4%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E5%A3%B0). But again, it is practically never used beyond two or three.

There is also 〜[鳴]{な}き for sounds coming from certain animals, including birds and insects (e.g. cicadas). 鳴き is a noun form of the verb 鳴く.

I cannot think of any counter for sounds that come from other sources than animals.